# Настройка конфигурации Hibernate в Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee, config

Использую версии Spring 5.0.8., Hibernate 5.3.4. Собираю web приложение в gradle. Задача: настроить конфигурацию Hibernate в Spring.
При запуске выскакивает `ConfigurationException` в тестах. (`Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException at MySqlDaoFactoryTest)`. Что я делаю не так, буду рад любой помощи.
файл `web-context.xml`(располагается в директории `webapp/WEB-INF`):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd"
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd"
        default-autowire="byName">
        <context:component-scan base-package="main" />
        <context:annotation-config/>
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conn.properties" />
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="MySqlDaoFactory" class="dao.MySqlDaoFactory">
        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">1</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">10</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statement">100</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>domain.Student</value>
                    <value>domain.Subjects</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="session" class="dao.MySqlDaoFactory"
        factory-bean="MySqlDaoFactory" factory-method="getSession">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
    ...
```

DAO:

```
public class MySqlDaoFactory extends DAOFactory{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session = null;
    public Session getSession() throws DAOException {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("Error of session", e);
        }
        return session;
    }
     public StudentDao getStudentDAO(Session session){
        return new MySqlStudentDao(session);
    }
    public SubjectDao getSubjectDAO(Session session){
        return new MySqlSubjectDao(session);
    }
}
```

зависимости в gradle:

```
compile group: 'jstl', name: 'jstl', version:'1.2'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.46'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '5.0.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-core', version: '9.0.10'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-logging-juli', version: '9.0.0.M6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '9.0.10'
    compile group: 'com.bmuschko', name: 'gradle-tomcat-plugin', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.4.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version: '5.3.4.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.3.4.Final'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.5.0'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version:'3.1.0'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.14.3'
```

Тест:

```
 public class MySqlDaoFactoryTest {
    static DAOFactory daoFactory;
    @BeforeClass
    static void initAll() {
        daoFactory = new MySqlDaoFactory();
    }
    @Test
    void connectionTest() throws DAOException {
        Session session = daoFactory.getSession();
        assertNotNull(session, "Connection failed");
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/web-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:739)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1372)
    ... 51 more
```

файл conn.properties:

```
driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
username = root
password = root
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_db?useSSL=false
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: (Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException at MySqlDaoFactoryTest). Все тесты Failed, будто нет соединения с базой данных из-за неверной конфигурации

Comment: Обычно полный текст ошибки занимает несколько строк, а в случае Spring и Hibernate несколько сотен строк.

Comment: При развертывании на Tomcat: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] for bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/web-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Comment: По какой-то причине Apache Commons DBCP или не включается в war-файл или не ищется в нём сервером. Откройте war-файл архиватором и убедитесь, что commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar в нём есть.

Comment: Какой пул вам надо?

Comment: в принципе все равно какой, главное чтобы работал

Comment: библиотеки загружаются
исправил в xml: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource на org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource
теперь выскакивает: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

Comment: возможно связано с загрузкой conn. properties, правильно ли я это делаю:
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conn.properties" />
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
        </bean>

Comment: файл conn.properties:
driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
username = root
password = root
url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_db?useSSL=false (для удобства просмотра добавил в вопрос)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать  менеджер источников данных от Spring:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}"/>
  <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
  <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: спасибо) так и сделал