# Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Столкнулся со странной проблемой, перестал запускаться спринг, после добавления второго модуля.

**Вот pom:**

```
<modules>
    <module>SecondModule</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.home</groupId>
<artifactId>FirstModule</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>FirstModule</name>
<description>FirstModule</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.14</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots-meta</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vdurmont</groupId>
        <artifactId>emoji-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**Вот application.properties**

```
server.port=8081
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_users
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**Пробовал разные драйвера:**

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

**Пробовал разные зависимости**

mysql
mysql-connector-java

Чистил кеш в ideas, удалял все папки .m2,.idea,.jdks, перекачивал все зависимости, пересоздавал проект, пробовал через аннотацию source указывать путь к файлу, начинает ругаться, что такого файла нет

Как добавляется второй модуль, все просто рушится. application.properties, находится в папке resources, все маркировки у папок верные
recources - resources root
java - sources root

**Полный текст ошибки**

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

**Main class**

```
  import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class CryptoExchangeApplication {
    
        publi

c static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(CryptoExchangeApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте сконфигурировать источники данных вручную. Это можно сделать примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/868938/204920).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С текущим проектом, проблему так и не решил, конфигурировать вручную, совсем не хотелось, так как не решает проблему и не дает ясности, в чем именно косяк.

Создал новый проект, так же с двумя модулями, но оба модуля, работают на спринге.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).